# Theme affecting code function?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-theme

Is there some reason applying a theme to an activity would affect the code function?  I was under the impression that styles/themes merely affected appearance...

I have a listfragment (filled from a database) with a button at the bottom, upon the press of that button a new activity is launched to allow you to edit or add to the list/database.

```
Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), Activity2.class);
startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_EDIT);
```

This second activity works as it should and upon exiting back to the listfragment, said list is updated and the new item appears in the list.

Here's where I start having an issue...

Since the second activity is only a TextView, EditText and two buttons, I thought I would use the dialog theme to keep it from taking up the entire tablet screen unnecessarily.  From the manifest file:

```
<activity android:name="Activity2" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />
```

This does achieve the result I was looking for as far as appearance of the activity goes, but upon exiting activity #2, the list in the listfragment is not regenerated/redisplayed.  The additon to the DB is being done, as I can see when I re-start the app the item I added previously finally appears.

The above addition to the manifest is the ONLY change made.

Any thoughts on why this is happening and how to stop it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or you could add code in `onResume()` to refresh it. When it calls the dialog, it calls `onPause()` and then calls `onResume()` when the dialog is exited.

Comment: This solved the issue, thanks very much!  However, I still don't understand why applying the dialog theme to the activity caused a change in the behavior of going from one of the activities to the other.  May just be one of those things I'll have to wonder about.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Your first activity isn't stopped and restarted when you launch a dialog, but it is when you launch a full screen activity.  Try calling [notifyDataSetChanged](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29) on the list adapter after the dialog activity finishes.